# Lazarus: Can I use environment var in the Project options library path (-Fl)?

Tags: environment-variables, lazarus, freepascal

In Delphi I can pass to library path a string `$(DelphiCommonLibs)\superobject\superobject-1.2`. Where `DelphiCommonLibs` is the system env var `DelphiCommonLibs=d:\DelphiCommonLibs`.

During build IDE replces the env var to actual value so the path becomes `d:\DelphiCommonLibs\superobject\superobject-1.2`

It's very convinient bacuse we don't need to stick to an absolute path. A developer should only need to chackout a libs repository and set the env var.

Is it possible in Lazarus?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a macros `$Env(name)`. Found in a very old post [here](https://hghltd.yandex.net/yandbtm?fmode=inject&url=https%3A%2F%2Flazarus.lazarus.freepascal.narkive.com%2F2DSdwD0u%2Fenvironment-variables-in-ide-s-search-path&tld=ru&lang=en&la=1539910784&tm=1540371547&text=lazarus%20library%20search%20path%20environment%20variable&l10n=ru&mime=html&sign=0476df9a5e8a130f9c75b90d1fa01bfc&keyno=0).